# Moving from VPS to Azure

Tags: azure

I have an IIS server on VPS.
I'm thinking about switching to Azure, but the problems are:

1. I have 7-8 old applications (that currently cannot be replaced and using classic asp)
2. I have many different applications pools

The questions is if there is some tool to move my entire IIS (including all the rules, applications pools and everything) to Azure or my only option is to move the apps one by one?

Comment: You can create a VHD of your existing server, then sysprep and upload it to Azure. http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-create-upload-vhd-windows-server/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you got a VM from Azure, you can move the entire VM.

Otherwise you'll need to move your applications one by one if you are moving to azure Web-Sites. But there is an export tool in IIS with Web-Deploy that can help you with applications settings: http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy/export-a-package-through-iis-manager